# JavaScript: Como posso obter/alterar um atributo dentro do Placeholder ="{"id":"10","selected":false}"

Tags: javascript, atributos, elementos

**Oi Gente**.

Primeiramente eu nem sabia que dava para colocar esses atributos dentro
do Placeholder, hehehe, nunca tinha visto mesmo.

```
<div class="cellContent" placeholder="{"id":"103","selected":false}"></div>
```

Se possível algum de vocês podem me enviar algum link onde têm alguma explicação sobre esse recurso... porque não achei nada sobre esses atributos em específico, mas o mais importante mesmo e se vocês sabem como alterar utilizar eles, surgiu essa dúvida em mim.

De algo mais ou menos assim: alterar a propredade (selected) ou verificar qual
o id que contém.

Tamo junto.

Comment: Não pode colocar `"` dentro de `"`. Se olhar para html interpretado vai ver que não é o que escreveu, logo é incorreto mesmo.

Comment: Qual o jeito certo para isso?